# How can I clear nuget cache in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How can I clear nuget cache in Azure Functions?
Some changes happend to our nuget package but version wasn't changed. (The package in dev now, and we can't change the version now, it should be the same)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question - unfortunately, there may be some tricky side effects. I'd recommend updating the package version appropriately so that the nuget restore always works as intended.

To see nuget caches, navigate to `portal -> function app -> platform features -> console`.

In the console, run `nuget locals all -list` to see local package caches. The problem you may have is that some these caches are stored locally on the vm, and we don't expose a console which can run a command on *all* vms. `nuget locals all -clear` is the command to clear the package cache, but it likely won't do what you want (clear the cache across all instances).

The nuget packages for your function are stored at `%HOME%\data\Functions\packages`, which is part of the shared file system. You can replace the package there with the updated package.